# SVG Logo on Microsoft Edge is showing 10 times bigger than other browsers

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am using a svg logo for my website, as shown below:

```
<img alt="" class="logo logo-dark" src="images/logo-dark.svg">
```

The svg file contains the following information about the size:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="-274.1 380.7 46 41.9" width="40">
```

to determine the width.

Even though it is shown correctly in all browsers, in Microsoft Edge it is shown 10 times bigger.

What am I missing out?

**Update:** The `.logo` has `max-width:100%`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the width in the svg, use it in the img tag like this:

```
<img alt="" class="logo logo-dark" src="images/logo-dark.svg" width="40">
```

You can also set both height and width on the svg instead of only width.